# How to read dem files in python pyvista

Tags: python, pyvista

i have .dem files like those here:
http://ddfe.curtin.edu.au/models/ERTM2160/data/dem/

In python pyvista i have eg:

```
import pyvista as pv
file = 'pick_one_from_the_link_above.dem'
mesh = pv.read(file)
```

The output says:

```
mesh.dimensions
[-2147483648,-2147483648,1]
```

which ist, except for the minus sign, the square root of mesh.n_points

Trying to plot or extract the points with mesh.points i get a message that negative dimensions are not allowed. Trying the folowing:

```
mesh.dimensions = [int(numpy.sqrt(mesh.n_points)),int(numpy.sqrt(mesh.n_points)),1]
```

results in an error message:

OverflowError: SetDimensions argument 1: value is out of range for int

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong, i have no idea? Or maybe has an idea how to read those files for making a surface plot?

Thanks alot :)

Comment: According to [the docs](http://ddfe.curtin.edu.au/models/ERTM2160/ERTM2160_readme.dat), the file you're reading is just a collection of signed 16-bit integers in big-endian format. As far as I can tell, the `dem` reader in `pyvista`, which uses `vtk.vtkDEMReader`,  is expecting [*this* DEM file format](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000285.shtml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@larsks is correct in the comment above. These ".dem" files are not in the format that PyVista and the VTK reader it wraps expect. You should use `np.fromfile` to read the data: `arr = np.fromfile('N00E015.dem', dtype=np.int16)`. Further from [the docs listed at your link](http://ddfe.curtin.edu.au/models/ERTM2160/ERTM2160_readme.dat):

> Due to its total size of 44 GB, the model is partitioned and distributed in
> terms of 881 binary files of 5 deg x 5 deg size for each functional. Each 5 deg
> x 5 deg tile contains 2500 x 2500 grid points in centre-of-cell representation
> (grid points are not situated on integer meridians and parallels)

You'll just create a `pv.UniformGrid` of that size and add the data. For instance:

```py
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

arr = np.fromfile('N00E015.dem', dtype=np.int16)

grid = pv.UniformGrid()
grid.dimensions = (2500, 2500, 1)
grid.origin = (0, 0, 0) # you need to figure this out
grid['dem'] = arr

grid.plot()
```

[image]

In order to get the correct spatial reference for the grid, you'll need to set the `origin` point of each subset/grid.

Further, the PyVista community is more active on the PyVista support forum than on Stack Overflow: https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista-support

Comment: Did not recognized that this had not been regular dem files. Thanks alot for all the information and also for the short demo code, it helped alot :)